# Remove the tag registrykey in favor of registry

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101844/how-to-rename-a-sid-key-in-registry) with [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registry) and [registrykey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registrykey). [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registry) is fine but I don't think we really need we need tags for [registrykey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registrykey) since then we might as well just make the other registry terms....[registrysubkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registrysubkey), [registryvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registryvalue), [registrytype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registrytype), [registrydata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registrydata) which just seems silly.

I don't even think it should be a synonym. Should we just get rid of [registrykey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registrykey) in favor of the more widely used [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registry)? At this point it is only 174 questions. Most I have seen already have [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registry) so we should just be able to remove the other. The others that do not should have [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registry) as it is more widely followed.

Comment: Where do I registry?